# Dispatching and redefinitions

Tags: java, dispatch

I have two library (ClassA and ClassB) classes and a runner class. Now I have a update of a library class (ClassAUpdate) which causes problems with my current runner class.

I think one of the problem is the because of redispatching this will have a infinite recursion. But there should be two more problems that I cant found. Maybe redefinition?

And how can I make changes only to the runner class to get this running without these problems? Maybe with a new class in the runner class that has the ClassB as component?

ClassA:

```
abstract class LibClassA
{
    public int m1( int param )
   {
      return m5( param / 2 );
   }

   public int m2( int param )
   {
      return param + 45;
   }

   abstract public int m3( int param );

   public int m5( int param )
   {
      return param * 6;
   }
}
```

ClassB:

```
class LibClassB extends LibClassA
{
   public int m1( int param )
   {
      int result = 773 - super.m1( param + 5 );
      if( param < 4 )
      {
          result += m2( param );
      }
      return result;
   }
   public int m3( int param )
   {
      return m1( param * 2 ) + 23;
   }
}
```

ClassAUpdate:

```
abstract class LibClassA
{
   public int m1( int param )
   {
      if( param >= 10 )
      {
          return m2( m5 (param, 5) );
      }
      else
      {
         return m4( param );
      }
   }

   public int m2( int param )
   {
      return param + 45;
   }

   abstract public int m3( int param );

   public int m4( int param )
   {
      return m5( param / 2, 6 );
   }

   public int m5( int param, int param2 )
   {
      return param * param2;
   }
}
```

Runner Class:

```
class OwnClass extends LibClassB
{

   public int m2( int param )
   {
      return 5 * m3( param );
   }
   public int m4( int param )
   {
      return param * param;
   }

   public int m5( int param )
   {
      return 165;
   }

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      OwnClass obj = new OwnClass();
      System.out.println( obj.m3( 2 ) );
      System.out.println( obj.m4( 9 ) );
      System.out.println( obj.m3( 3 ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the intention of this code? I couldn't understand it

Comment: It doesnt have a specific intention. It only makes some calculation and it is only to show some problems when updating libraries. So at first you have ClassA and ClassB and Runner Class. Everything runs fine. Then when you exchange ClassA with ClassAUpdate you are getting some problems. For example indefinte recursion.